# Control Dropbox upload rate on the command line

Tags: limit, bandwidth, dropbox

I'm using Dropbox without the GUI in Linux. I would like to limit the upload rate, sometimes large files eats my internet bandwidth. Anyone knows how I do that?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can start the Dropbox executable under [trickle](http://monkey.org/~marius/pages/?page=trickle). This is a simple program that limits the bandwidth used by the program that it starts.

```
trickle -u 42 dropbox.py
```

Comment: Great idea! Unfortunately trickle together with dropbox causes 100% CPU for me - [any ideas?](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/141036/trickle-bandwidth-shaper-with-dropbox-causes-100-cpu)

Answer (score 1):

If using the [CLI program](https://www.dropbox.com/download?dl=packages/dropbox.py) provided by Dropbox, then the builtin throttling can easily be accessed.

**Example**

```
./dropbox.py throttle 2000 100
```

**Documentation**

> `$ ./dropbox.py throttle help`
>   set bandwidth limits for Dropbox
>   dropbox throttle DOWNLOAD UPLOAD
>
> Set bandwidth limits for file sync.
>
> DOWNLOAD - either "unlimited" or a manual limit in KB/s
>   UPLOAD - one of "unlimited", "auto", or a manual limit in KB/s

Answer (score 1):

For dropbox this doesn't work well since the runner script is just that, a script.

In order for trickle to have any effect it needs to be run on the binary itself.

e.g.

trickle -s -u 100 -d 200 -w 5 ~/.dropbox-dist/dropbox-lnx.x86_64-54.4.90/dropbox

but the version number can change!