# trickle (bandwidth shaper) with dropbox causes 100% CPU

Tags: bandwidth, dropbox

I'm limiting dropbox upload bandwith with [trickle](https://packages.debian.org/jessie/trickle) as suggested [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/115093/control-dropbox-upload-rate-on-the-command-line).

```
@reboot trickle -u 100 ~/.dropbox-dist/dropboxd
```

This works great but unfortunately causes 100% CPU - even with only 2-3 (small) files in total. On its own Dropbox only consumes about 1-2% CPU (without trickle).

What might cause this CPU hog? Is there any other way to throttle Dropbox upload speed?

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/34116/how-can-i-limit-the-bandwidth-used-by-a-process

Comment: @krowe No: that thread provides other techniques to achieve the same thing, but doesn't address why this particular technique doesn't work.

Comment: What versions of trickle and dropbox do you have? Have you checked their bug list? What distribution are you using?

Answer (score 1):

I have no idea if this is still relevant.
With Dropbox on Linux you can right click on the applet - select preferences - bandwidth and change the allowed the download and upload rate.