# Dropbox GUI issues in Fedora 23 running Cinnamon

Tags: fedora, cinnamon, gui, dropbox

I am having an issue with Dropbox under Fedora 23 and I don't know how to fix it. Take a look at the following pic:

[image]

So regarding this I have two questions:

- Is there any way to fix this? How? I am missing something
- If there is not solution or work around how do I limit the upload speed to 10 or 15kb from the command line? Any config file?

I have found [this](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/115093/control-dropbox-upload-rate-on-the-command-line) topic but is not so helpful since it relates to command line only.